# SQL storage sizing - How to get statistics of what data is being accessed

Tags: sql-server, windows, storage

*How can I monitor which data is being accessed and which frequency?*

I'm in need to migrate several (very) small SQL Server instances, each which several small databases. Current configuration is based in a lot of also small servers with local storage. New configuration is based in a single server with a single NAS.

So far, the SQL Server memory and CPU sizing is OK. Also DB sizes and total IOPS. But there's no existing documentation of what data set is actually being accessed. So, basically, I don't have a clue about what are the real storage requirements since the **total** amount of IOPS may be for only a couple of tables (so it would work like a charm with just a couple of SSD) or if the whole set of databases are being scanned all the time and I'll need several dozens of disks.

So, back to the question: *How can I "profile" and get statistics of what data is being accessed? Either at SQL or Windows level?*

Comment: This is not a programming question and will be closed.  Please consider posting on DBA stack exchange.

Comment: … or waiting for it to be moved with a few more close votes.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to see how much a table or groups of tables are being used is to use SQL Server Audit. It has very little impact on SQL Server's performance and can be easily set up to monitor selects (unlike triggers) in addition to  inserts/updates/deletes.

Comment: This is a site for programming questions, not DBA questions.  If someone asked a question about puppies here and you answered it, that does not mean asking such a question is appropriate.